# flexslider multiple image slider(carousel). Need a page count like 1 of 2, 2 of 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, flexslider

Trying to implement multiple thumbnail images carousel using flexslider. But not able create page count for the image carousel.

Like suppose if **12 items** are there, I want to show 6 at a time which is considered as 1st page and the remaining in 2nd slide. It should show the page count **1 of 2** for 1st 6 images and **2 of 2** for next images. Based the number of images page count has to be implemented.

Attaching the link for reference:
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

I am using flexslider for it. I referred the documentation, but not able to figure out the proper solution.

If anyone can come up with the solution it would be helpful.

Regards